Tech contractor not renewed for suspicious reasons
Sorry it is long but please read and give me advice!
Background: I (none indian) have been treated poorly in my role, with TWO employees (employee A & employees B both indian) frequently pushing me to take on multiple projects and do their tasks without any clear opportunities for career growth. My manager reduced our 1:1 meetings over the past 11 months, creating an environment where their employees took advantage of my position as a contractor.[I have never discussed this to anyone]
I have been working as a yearly contractor for the company in a technical role. My contract was renewed last year, and I consistently received positive feedback from my manager over the past two years. However, after the renewal, there was no formal communication about a change in my management, and my manager started minimizing our interactions.
Employee B I worked closely with was promoted and moved to another project. I covered his responsibilities during his transition, and the company began backfilling his position. I applied for the role, informed my manager of my interest, and waited for a month, only to learn that they were considering someone else without inviting me for an interview. Around the same time, I discovered they had posted my position online as another contract role.
Feeling disappointed, I approached my manager to discuss my contract. He claimed that there was no budget to renew it. I showed him the job postings for my role that I found, and he dismissed them, suggesting they were from other departments and had no relevance.
When I brought up the permanent position I’d applied for, he offered another excuse, saying he’d heard from a colleague, Employee A, that I was slow with tasks and didn’t understand them well. When I questioned why he accepted this feedback, he was unable to give a clear response, only saying that everything had been good when he was managing me. He mentioned he would arrange a meeting with everyone involved to address this.
Now, despite the positive feedback I’ve received over the past two years. Additionally, I applied for an internal position, but they didn’t consider my application. When I inquired about the reason, my manager cited negative feedback from Employee A.
I requested a 3 way meeting with the boss and that employee to question why he said that. Looking forward to  that meeting and will update you about that

As far as I understood you, you have a limited time contract right now. Why would they need to fake any reason for anything? They are not required to hire you as an employee, they are not required to give you another contract after this one. What exactly would they fake and why?

It sounds like they may be initiating this performance review as a way to create a formal record that justifies not renewing the contract or potentially pushing me out. Thier reasons were swinging and review thing is totally made up, because I have never had any negative reviews, I always was asking my manager about his feedbacks

Why would they need such a reason if you are a contractor? What would happen if they just said "it was great working with you, but we are going with someone else next year". Do you live somewhere, where not hiring you for another contract would need a reason?

@nikki - They don’t need any reason to not renew your contract.

@nvoigt, do not twist my words, I am asking why do I need to have this meeting when I am not being renewed?  they simply mentioned they do not have any budget, why do I need to attend this meeting?

I assume you get paid for being in this meeting as part of your existing contract, are you not?

They had two years to provide feedback, I do not see any need for feedback now, I was always asked for feedback for the past 2 years, and it was always positive . I am available for any other work-related meeting but not this at the moment, as time passed.

"He mentioned he would arrange a meeting with everyone involved to address this." This sounds like a good reason to have a performance review. Why do you rule this out as a reason, and instead focus on something that - even in your own words - isn't reason to have such a review?

because those two colleagues are insulting me even now after that conversation with my manager. If they had any intention of listening I would give it a chance.

So you are now 95% sure that the company will ditch you and you still hope to solve things amiably?
The short and full answer is: start looking for a new job. Either switch jobs at the end of the current contract, or earlier - see the details of your current contract to understand how it is best to proceed.

Yes, you are right, I wonder why they want me even meet and discuss this made up performance review? It sounds like they may be initiating this performance review as a way to create a formal record that justifies not renewing the contract or potentially pushing me out. I do not see any need to participate in this meeting or have it in the first place. How do I need to act in that meeting? or about participating in it?

Just behave normally, react as you feel. Do not just act. There is still 5% chance that something good will happen. The idea is that things do not look optimistic now, and it is much better / safer for you to have good alternatives. It is very usual for  companies / managers to talk one thing and do another. E.g., you get one kind of feedback during the year (everything OK), and another one during the evaluation (when they present you each and every thing that offended them throughout the year - and goodbye salary increase or bonuses).

That is correct, I was considering staying silent initially and letting them speak, but if they accuse me of false claims, I want to be prepared to defend myself. What do you recommend I bring with me to the meeting?

I hope you do not expect me to say "bring a Kalashnikov" :)) Bring relaxation and peace of mind. In that way, you can react better to anything that can happen / can be discussed during the meeting. Be prepared for the worst - which probably is some accusations (real or fake) and termination of contract. If you are at peace with that outcome, then everything else can be only better.

I was asking what should and what not should I say during this meeting?

@nikki: you should say very little and listen a lot. Ask mostly factual clarification question. It's  also good practice to ask for specific example for anything you yet dinged on. Don't argue in the meeting even if treated unfairly. They are way better prepared than you are. You'll need some time to formulate your reply and strategy. And yes, chances are you are on your way out so start looking now,

I am asking why do I need to have this meeting when I am not being renewed? they simply mentioned they do not have any budget, why do I need to attend this meeting?They had two years to provide feedback, I do not see any need for feedback now, I always asked for feedback for the past 2 years, and it was always positive . I am available for any other work-related meeting but not this at the moment, as time passed.

@nikki: It is a sign of good education from your side to attend  a meeting when your manager invites you. If you do not attend, your manager can do things that can hurt you professionally. So just keep calm and go with the wave. Until you change the wave completely.

You are a contractor.
Having customers as a "Referable Client" is important for contractors. Clearly having a work history of happy clients is important for getting new clients quickly and at high pay.
I am bringing this up before even addressing the idea of becoming an employee. That is because you are describing a client that would likely not give you a favorable recommendation.
You are describing a situation where your view and their view is different. It doesn't have to be fair nor correct. It could be just internal politics and you are receiving consequence. Most of us have been in similar situations. Mitigating the future harm to your career would be a good plan.
Ask yourself, do you have a future with the company as long as this management team is in place?
Consider focusing on how to get your next client rather than dreaming for the unlikely event that this client will hire you fulltime. Keep in mind that we are random internet people and these are your decisions. Good luck

I am asking why do I need to have this meeting when I am not being renewed? they simply mentioned they do not have any budget, why do I need to attend this meeting?They had two years to provide feedback, I do not see any need for feedback now, I always asked for feedback for the past 2 years, and it was always positive . I am available for any other work-related meeting but not this at the moment, as time passed.

As a contractor, as long as you are still on their contract they can have the meeting at their pleasure. If you are no longer under contract and there is no work with them available, there is no reason to have the meeting unless they are paying you for your time. If you do have to take this meeting because you still are being paid, say nothing in response to anything other than "Thank you for your feedback". Do not let them infuriate you into a fight or saying something that could be considered a reason for them to not use your services.

Your specific question is:  Why might they be initiating a performance review now, and how should I approach this situation in the meeting?
You approach it as part of your workdays tasks and go to the meeting.  It dosn't matter. We don't know why they are doing it.  I certainly wouldn't spend effort on a contractor at all, especially one who wasn't being renewed. You are being paid, so just attend the meeting, say thank you, and when your contract is up find another place to work.  If you disagree with their findings, just say "I disagree, but I accept receipt of your performance review." There is no upside to complaining about it.
